# Add random css classes to random elements with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

I have 75 divs with multiple products, I need to display random badges to random products.

This is html where badge is displayed :

```
<div class="badge"> </div>
```

This is my script which is adding random classes to **all** elements with class badge, I want to add random classes to **random products** .

```
var classes = ['lastBadge', 'offerBadge', 'stockBadge'];
var prevClass = "";
$('.badge').each(function() {
var classes2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (classes[i] !== prevClass) {
        classes2.push(classes[i]);
    }
}
$(this).addClass(prevClass =classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)]);
console.log(prevClass);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition when applying the class

```
var percentage = 50;
if(Math.random() > percentage/100)
   $(this).addClass(prevClass =classes2[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes2.length)]);
```

Change percentage to decide how many products get a badge (statistically...)

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly take your classes one by one, and in every iteration apply and remove the used one:

```js
var classes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

$(".badge").each(function() {
  if (classes.length === 0) return false; // break jQuery each

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length);
  var className = classes[index];
  
  console.log(className);
  $(this).addClass(className);
  classes.splice(index, 1);
});
```

```css
.badge.A {
  background-color: #777;
}

.badge.B {
  background-color: #888;
}

.badge.C {
  background-color: #999;
}

.badge.D {
  background-color: #AAA;
}

.badge.E {
  background-color: #BBB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="badge">1</div>
<div class="badge">2</div>
<div class="badge">3</div>
<div class="badge">4</div>
<div class="badge">5</div>
<div class="badge">6</div>
<div class="badge">7</div>
<div class="badge">8</div>
```

You may want to clone your array using `Array.from` or `[].slice.call` in order to not loose your classes list after applying.

Comment: Move the script to after the divs are loaded, or use 'ready' state because the divs aren't loaded when the function is running, and nothing works on the preview on SO :)

Comment: @Narxx It works for me...Stackoverflow always places scripts in snippets **after** HTML.

Comment: you are correct. I have blocked jQuery without noticing. Get a +1 for your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i have 10 divs only first 5 divs will have a random class added. And how can only some divs will have a random css and some not. Like from 30 divs ..only 15 divs to have a random css from css array.https://jsfiddle.net/wdau9ust/

Comment: Just give a class to those divs you want to have a random class. In this example, the class is badge. You can set a different class to loop through.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```js
var classes = ['lastBadge', 'offerBadge', 'stockBadge'];

var randomBadges = function() {
  var divCount = 75;
  var randomDivCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount);
  var randomEl, randomClass;

  do {
    randomEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * divCount);
    randomClass = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    $('.badge').eq(randomEl).addClass(randomClass);
    randomDivCount--;
  } while (randomDivCount >= 0);
}

randomBadges();
```

```css
.badge {
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.lastBadge {
  background: red;
}
.offerBadge {
  background: green;
}
.stockBadge {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
<div class="badge"></div>
```